# Apache execution permission needed to display webpage

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions

I am currently experiencing something weird where apache has to have execution permission in order to display pages. This is the permissions currently set on the directory where admin has all permissions and apache only has read permission. Nevertheless I am having a 403 when trying to access the index.

Am I missing something? I thought that only read permission was needed for apache to be able to display pages?

```
drwxr-----  3 admin www-data 4096 Apr  4 12:27 assets
drwxr-----  3 admin www-data 4096 Apr  4 12:27 css
drwxr-----  3 admin www-data 4096 Apr  4 12:27 images
-rwxr-----  1 admin www-data  469 Apr  4 12:27 index.php
drwxr----- 15 admin www-data 4096 Apr  4 12:27 protected
drwxr-----  4 admin www-data 4096 Apr  4 12:27 themes
```

The virtualhost is as follow:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName ****
    ServerAlias ****
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile ****
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ****
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/share
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT per request:

Permissions on /home/sites/share

```
drwxr----- 8 admin www-data 4096 Apr  4 14:52 share
```

Permissions on /home/sites

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 admin admin  4096 Apr  4 12:27 sites
```

Permissions on /home

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Apr  2 18:01 home
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the /home/sites/share directory itself? You should be able to get away with read permission on files but all directories that Apache needs to access also need execute permission.

Comment: As files don't need execute permission, you shouldn't need the execute bit set for owner on index.php (or any other files), just directories - chmod 640 should suffice for index.php.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dug a bit and found out that there is an error on :

Permission denied: /home/sites/share/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable


I added the .htaccess and it's readable by apache, still the same error

Comment: So what are the permissions on the /home/sites/share folder? In fact it may make more sense to just add the permissions of /home, /home/sites & /home/sites/share to the question

Comment: Edited the original post with the permissions you requested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The share directory needs execute permission for the www-data group. Without execute permission, members of the www-data group (i.e. Apache) can not access the contents of that directory.

```
chmod 750 /home/sites/share
```

Edit: Obviously any other directories Apache needs access to, such as assets/images/etc above, and any subfolders of these will also need execute permission for the group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's indeed working with execution permission. Could you please be more specific as such why execution permission is needed?

Comment: It's a well known "feature" of UNIX permissions/file systems that you need execute permission on a directory to access it. There's loads of responses and information on the numerous other questions about the same thing - such as http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened